# Change of basis between bases with different rank

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Textbooks deal with a change of basis between eigenstates of the same ranked operator, for example, between spin-1/2 $x$ and $y$ directions. Can we think of general transformation between bases which are the eigenstate of different ranked operators?

For example, when one state is represented in position ($x$) bases, can we have the unitary or any sort of transformation that makes it in spin (assuming intrinsic spin is known) bases?

If so, how can we do our example - spin to position bases transformation?

Comment: Yes we can and the transformation matrix wont be n×n.

Comment: because the position is continuous I think it is not desirable to use matrix representation. How can one represent |x> in terms of a|+;z>+b|-;z> for a spin-1/2 particle?

Comment: of course the coefficients a = <x|+;z> and b=<x|-;z>. My question is how to determine those values.